# JQ: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 3

Tags: json, schema, jq

I actually move some of my equipment and changed the OS for some VMs. I use jq 1.5 under Windows 10 and got now an error with a json Transformation. I use following jq command:

```
C:\import\Dreamlines\jq.exe "[{nid, includesservices: .includedServices, title, nights, company: .operator.shortTitle, zone: .zones[0].title, schiffsbeschreibung: .ship.factsAndFigures} + (.sails[] | ({ sails_nid: .nid, arrival, departure } + (.cabins[] | { cabinname: .cabinType.title, cabintype: .cabinType.kindName, cabinnid: .cabinType.nid, catalogPrice, discountPrice, discountPercentage, currency } )))   ]" C:\import\Dreamlines\dreamlines_details.json | out-file -encoding Unicode -filepath C:\import\Dreamlines\import_sails.json
```

To generate following json:

```
[{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Innenkabine Fantastica (Kat. I2):",
    "cabintype": "Innenkabine",
    "cabinnid": 2919,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Innenkabine Bella (Kat. I1):",
    "cabintype": "Innenkabine",
    "cabinnid": 232847,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Außenkabine Bella (Kat. O1): ",
    "cabintype": "Außenkabine",
    "cabinnid": 232848,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Außenkabine Fantastica (Kat. O2): ",
    "cabintype": "Außenkabine",
    "cabinnid": 232849,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Balkonkabine Bella (Kat. B1): ",
    "cabintype": "Balkonkabine",
    "cabinnid": 232850,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Balkonkabine Fantastica (Kat. B2): ",
    "cabintype": "Balkonkabine",
    "cabinnid": 232851,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Balkonkabine Aurea (Kat. B3): ",
    "cabintype": "Balkonkabine",
    "cabinnid": 232853,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Aurea Suite (Kat. S3): ",
    "cabintype": "Suite",
    "cabinnid": 232854,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Deluxe Suite (Kat. YC1): ",
    "cabintype": "Suite",
    "cabinnid": 232855,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Executive & Family Suite (Kat. YC2): ",
    "cabintype": "Suite",
    "cabinnid": 232856,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Royal Suite (Kat. YC3): ",
    "cabintype": "Suite",
    "cabinnid": 232857,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Deluxe Suite Kat. YH1",
    "cabintype": "Suite",
    "cabinnid": 243945,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
},
{
    "nid": 509660,
    "includesservices": "<ul>\r\n\r\n<li>Kreuzfahrt ab/bis Dubai auf der MSC Splendida</li>\r\n<li>Unterkunft in der gebuchten Kabinenkategorie</li>\r\n<li>Vollpension, d.h. Frühstück, Mittagessen, Nachmittagstee, Snacks, Abendessen</li>\r\n<li>Vielfältiges Sportangebot, inkl. Nutzung Fitnesscenter und Open-Air- Sportanlagen</li>\r\n<li>Entertainment</li>\r\n<li>Qualifizierte Kinderbetreuung</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n",
    "title": "Von Dubai über Manama in 15 Tagen",
    "nights": 14,
    "company": "MSC",
    "zone": "Emirate und Orient",
    "schiffsbeschreibung": "<p><strong>Schiffsdaten</strong></p>\r\n<ul>\r\n<li>Inbetriebnahme: 2009</li>\r\n<li>Länge: 333 m</li>\r\n<li>Höhe: 67 m</li>\r\n<li>Breite: 38 m</li>\r\n<li>Tiefgang: 8,45 m</li>\r\n<li>Tonnage: 137.936 BRT</li>\r\n<li>Geschwindigkeit: 23 Knoten</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Decks: 18</li>\r\n<li>Anzahl der Kabine: 1.637</li>\r\n<li>Passagiere: 3.247</li>\r\n<li>Besatzung: 1.370</li>\r\n<li>Sprachen an Bord: Italienisch, Deutsch, Französisch, Englisch</li>\r\n<li>Bordwährung: US-Dollar, Euro</li>\r\n<li>Internet an Bord: Es gibt ein Internetcafé und in allen Kabinen kann eine Internetverbindung gegen einen Gebühr dazu gebucht werden.</li>\r\n</ul>\r\n",
    "sails_nid": 509662,
    "arrival": 1552694400,
    "departure": 1551484800,
    "cabinname": "Innenkabine Wellness (Kat. IW): ",
    "cabintype": "Innenkabine",
    "cabinnid": 360681,
    "catalogPrice": 0,
    "discountPrice": 0,
    "discountPercentage": 0,
    "currency": "EUR"
}
```

]

That works fine. I  use a second command to manipulate the Arrival/departue object:

```
C:\import\Dreamlines\jq.exe ".[].arrival |= todateiso8601 | .[].departure |= todateiso8601" C:\import\Dreamlines\import_sails.json | out-file -filepath C:\import\Dreamlines\date_sails.json -encoding Unicode
```

On the new system i got following error: JQ: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 3. First i thought the api changed some data but on the old system works that fine. I checked the json and the validor says that this is a valid json.

Tips?

Regards
Timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem not fixed, but i designed a work around (i merged both operations into one). I createe an issue @github vor that.
Thanks vor the help.

Regards
Timo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's valid JSON, but the jq query does not match at all.

First, the input JSON is an array, so presumably you want to use `map(...)` rather than `[...]`.  (Debugging hint: start small.]

Second, the schema of the JSON does not match the query. For example, the query supposes there is a key named `sails`, which does not exist anywhere in the JSON. (Debugging hint: use `schema.jq` to view the schema of a JSON document -- see below.)

### schema.jq

Using https://gist.github.com/pkoppstein/a5abb4ebef3b0f72a6ed with the last line uncommented:

```
$ jq -f schema.jq input.json
{
  "nid": "number",
  "includesservices": "string",
  "title": "string",
  "nights": "number",
  "company": "string",
  "zone": "string",
  "schiffsbeschreibung": "string",
  "sails_nid": "number",
  "arrival": "number",
  "departure": "number",
  "cabinname": "string",
  "cabintype": "string",
  "cabinnid": "number",
  "catalogPrice": "number",
  "discountPrice": "number",
  "discountPercentage": "number",
  "currency": "string"
}
```

Comment: Hi Peak,thanks vor your Input. I updated tue post since my description was wrong (that happens if i do two different thinks on the same time. Sorry

Comment: I tested several Points also the Schemata. I uploaded the original json before the first Transformation: [link]https://codeshare.io/2jvLNL . I changed the order and transformed the Arrival/departure first in the (original) json and starts then the rebuild. Same error. Still no idea. On another Windows System that works fine... Regards Timo

Comment: Hi Peak, sorry again but i didn't understand your point. The codeshare.io link is the original json file. Yes your are right that there are several Arrival/departure keys under different Arrays/objects. My first json command transform that original json into the posted json array. In that json i have only one arrival/departure key per object. The second command change the value of the arrival/departure key from the unix timestamp to a date. the Schemata analysis says that in the modified json all Arrival/departure fields are numbers. On jq Play or under unix or under a unpatched w10 works that

Comment: @TimoC - I tried to apply the first transformation (the one beginning "[{nid, ...") to the contents of the codeshare.io link, and I got the error message: `Cannot index number with string "sails"`

Comment: @TimoC - Some good news -- I've verified that applying the second filter to the JSON included in the Q does work.  So I'm wondering if the encoding of the file is correct. Can you run `jq length` on that file?  The result should be 13.

Comment: On which of both files? On the original or on the first transformed? Regards Timo

Comment: I run the following command on the transformed file: jq ".[] | length" and got also the error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 3

Comment: Problem still existing. I opened an issue @github for that.